# How to work on a Python project, on a remote linux server, locally on a macbook?

Tags: python-3.x, remote-server

I have a few python projects, that I am the only one working on. The environment is setup via venv. However, I cannot use the remote Python venv environment locally. I am newer to python. Locally, I am mounting the remote directory via ExpanDrive, connecting via SFTP on my mac.

Reason for this setup is some scripts are running via CRON periodically and, centralization. Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Installed `remote-ssh` in vscode and that solved the problem.